# GoogleImages-like listbox with detail panel

Tags: wpf, listbox

How would you design a Google images -like component?

I'm not sure how to handle the detail panel which shows under each image when selected.

The detail panel:
      - shows between two rows of images.
      - keep left and right items in place.

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to **LittleBit** for providing a very nice solution to the problem. Based on his hints, i created the following general-purpose component taking care of a few details you will eventually face when making **LittleBit** solution production-ready.

*file: DetailedList.cs*

```
public class DetailedList : ListBox
{
    #region DetailsTemplate
    public DataTemplate DetailsTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue( DetailsTemplateProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( DetailsTemplateProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DetailsTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( nameof( DetailsTemplate ), typeof( DataTemplate ), typeof( DetailedList ) );
    #endregion

    static DetailedList()
    {
        Type ownerType = typeof( DetailedList );

        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata( ownerType,
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( ownerType ) );

        StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata( ownerType,
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( null, ( depObj, baseValue ) =>
            {
                var element = depObj as FrameworkElement;
                if( element != null && baseValue == null )
                    baseValue = element.TryFindResource( ownerType );

                return baseValue;
            } ) );
    }
}
```

*file: StretchGrid.cs*

```
internal class StretchGrid : Grid
{
    private Expander _expander;

    #region ParentPanel
    public Panel ParentPanel
    {
        get { return (Panel)this.GetValue( ParentPanelProperty ); }
        set { this.SetValue( ParentPanelProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentPanelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof( ParentPanel ), typeof( Panel ), typeof( StretchGrid ), new PropertyMetadata( null, ParentPanelChanged ) );

    private static void ParentPanelChanged( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        var stretchGrid = d as StretchGrid;
        if( stretchGrid == null ) return;

        if( e.NewValue is Panel panel )
            panel.SizeChanged += stretchGrid.UpdateMargins;
    }
    #endregion

    public StretchGrid()
    {
        this.Loaded += StretchGrid_Loaded;
    }

    private void StretchGrid_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        _expander = this.FindLogicalParent<Expander>();

        _expander.Expanded += UpdateMargins;
        _expander.SizeChanged += UpdateMargins;

        this.UpdateMargins( null, null );
    }

    private void UpdateMargins( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        if( ParentPanel == null ) return;
        if( _expander == null ) return;

        Point delta = _expander.TranslatePoint( new Point( 0d, 0d ), ParentPanel );

        //Create negative Margin to allow the Grid to be rendered outside of the Boundaries (full row under the item)
        this.Margin = new Thickness( -delta.X, 0, delta.X + _expander.ActualWidth - ParentPanel.ActualWidth, 0 );
    }
}
```

*file: DetailedList.xaml*

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type cc:DetailedList}" TargetType="{x:Type cc:DetailedList}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">

    <Style.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="NoButtonExpander.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single"/>

    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cc:DetailedList}}}" 
                           Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">

                            <Border Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Expander Style="{StaticResource NoButtonExpander}" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                      IsExpanded="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" 
                                      Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}">

                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Expander.Header>

                                    <cc:StretchGrid ParentWrapPanel="{Binding Path=Tag, 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type WrapPanel}}}">

                                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding DetailsTemplate, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cc:DetailedList}}}"/>

                                    </cc:StretchGrid>
                                </Expander>
                            </Border>

                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

*file: NoButtonExpander.xaml*

```
<Style x:Key="ExpanderRightHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ExpanderUpHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Rectangle Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="NoButtonExpander" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Working on this - interesting question

Comment: Looking forward your ideas.

Comment: Idea was to use a container that understands Alternation. DataGrid was my Obvious choice first. Collection binding to Grid looks like having objects were each has an array of Images say 5/row. Then next row would be another VM (extending same parent) - which would serve as Details view. When you click any Cell from in a Row (x) -- I will make the Row x +1 Template visible which actually shows the Selected Item. However, I'm stuck at getting the Grid show all the items. If I have exactly 10 images (5/row) my UI doesnt render 2nd row at all. The moment I have 11 images. I see all 3 rows. Weird.

Comment: I guess it was comparatively simpler in html; as with jquery you can insert block of html at chosen place.

Comment: Following your idea, there's no need to have a separate vm for the details: the vm should already have all of the info we want, we just don't show them all in the standard row BUT we show all the information nicely in the detail row. Nice idea.

Comment: Wow - That really made my day... So now I would prefer ItemsControl (and not DataGrid). Each Item in this would be ArrayOfImages along with theDetails View which will stay hidden until Image is clicked... Great Thought. On it right away.

Comment: The problem with ItemsControl is that every item has a ItemContainer that contain all of your stuff, hidden and visible. It will move around the other items when you show the details part. I'm also stuck there

Comment: @LittleBit After hours of research and different approaches and trials, i solved the problem setting the VerticalAlignment="Top" on the Expander :), code updated. Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach is to use a `ListView` with some modifications

- The `ItemsPanel` of the `ListView` must have a 'wrap' function, so i used a `Wrappanel` to display the Image-Previews in a field.
- The `ItemContainter` of the `ListViewItem` must have two states. An Image-Preview state and a Detail-View therfore an `Expander` should do the trick.
- The Details of an Image must be displayed across the whole Column under the Image. We need something which renders outside the Boundaries of a `ListViewItem` (more later)

It now looks like this
[image: Image Details messed up]
The Image Details are now messed up due to the Boundaries. The `Height` is no problem because it just moves the next Column down until it fits in. The Problem is the `Width` and its Position (its not left aligned).

I created a small CustomControl, the `StretchGrid` which renders its `Content` across the whole Column and left aligned. This `StretchGrid` get the relative distance to the left Boundary and sets it as negative `Margin.Left` to render it properly. Now it looks like this (and i hope that is exactly what you are looking for).
[image: Image Details properly displayed]

Now the `Style` of the `ListView`

```
<!-- Image List with Detail -->
<Style x:Key="PicList" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <!-- Only one Picture can be selected -->
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single"/>

    <!-- Enable Multi-Line with a WrapPanel Around the Items -->
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (ListView.ActualWidth),RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!-- Override Display area of the Item -->
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">

                <!-- Define Image Item -->
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <!-- Use Expander Header as Preview/Thumbnail and display Details below when expanded -->
                            <Expander x:Name="PicThumbnail" Style="{StaticResource NoButtonExpander}" IsExpanded="{Binding (ListViewItem.IsSelected), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}" Width="{Binding (ListViewItem.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <!-- Thumbnail/Preview Section -->
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Source="/XAML;component/Assets/Images/Thumb.png" Height="16" Width="16" />
                                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <!-- Self stretching Grid (Custom Control) -->
                                <cc:StretchGrid x:Name="PicDetails" Background="LightGray" ParentWrappanel="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type WrapPanel}}}">
                                    <!-- Picture Detail Section (quick & dirty designed, replace later) -->
                                    <Image ClipToBounds="False" Source="/XAML;component/Assets/Images/Highres.png" Width="128" Height="128" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0" />
                                    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="128" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="128" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                    <StackPanel Margin="150,0">
                                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        <Label Content="Description: Lorem"/>
                                        <Label Content="Category: Ipsum"/>
                                        <Label Content="Owner: Dolor"/>
                                        <Label Content="Size: 5kB"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </cc:StretchGrid>
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <!-- Brings selected element to front, details see edit -->
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Note: Its necessary to add a Reference to the `StretchGrid`.

And the `StretchGrid` Custom Control

```
class StretchGrid : Grid
{
    //Reference for parent expander (used to calculate Grid Margin)
    private Expander m_expander;

    //Property for relativesource Binding to Wrappanel in Style
    public WrapPanel ParentWrappanel
    {
        get { return (WrapPanel)this.GetValue(Wrappanel); }
        set { this.SetValue(Wrappanel, value); }
    }

    //DependencyProperty for RelativeSource Binding to Wrappanel in Style (Note: the Binding is set inside the Style, not here programmatically in PropertyMetaData)
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Wrappanel = DependencyProperty.Register("ParentWrappanel", typeof(WrapPanel), typeof(StretchGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    //Constructor
    public StretchGrid() : base()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Loaded += Init;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.SizeChanged += UpdateMargins;
    }

    private void Init(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_expander = (Expander)this.Parent;                 //Change when xaml markup hirarchy changes
        if(m_expander != null)                              //(or make it similar to the Wrappanel with
        {                                                   //RelativeSource Binding)

            m_expander.Expanded += UpdateMargins;             //Update when expander is expanded
            m_expander.SizeChanged += UpdateMargins;          //Update when the expander changes the Size

            //Update all StretchGrids on Initialization
            UpdateMargins(null, null);
        }
    }

    //Calculate Grid Margin when an according Event is triggered
    private void UpdateMargins(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(ParentWrappanel != null)
        {
            Point delta = m_expander.TranslatePoint(new Point(0d, 0d), ParentWrappanel);

            //Create negative Margin to allow the Grid to be rendered outside of the Boundaries (full column under the Image)
            this.Margin = new Thickness(-delta.X, 0, delta.X + m_expander.ActualWidth - ParentWrappanel.ActualWidth, 0);
            //Theese Values arent calculated exavtly, just broad for example purpose
        }
    }
}
```

This is a little bit tricky to incorporate in existing Code. A working Example may help and is found [HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=04476739733744110786).

SideNote: If i got more time i would pack this stuff into a bigger Custom Control to use it like a normal `UIElement` (eg. `Border`). This would improve the re-usability and usability quite a lot.

---

**EDIT**

The 'newest' element in the `ListView` is also atop of the Z-Index, therefore it is 'above' the expanded `StretchGrid` and some Controls can not be clicked because they are 'behind' the next `ListviewItem`.

To fix this, add

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

to the `ListViewItem` Style. Now when its visible it will place itself atop the other Controls.

Comment: This is promising as it is a very clean solution. I'll try it out and feedback.

Comment: The StretchGrid is the absolute key to solve this problem gracefully. For this reason i'm marking your answer as the solution. Thanks. Based on your hints I'm taking care of a few details in order to make a general production-ready component. I will edit my question to include the relevant code. Thanks again!

Comment: No Problem, this Question is quite a satisfying Challenge. And Thank you too, your refactoring eases my next steps :)

Comment: I just refactored/updated the StretchGrid cpde in the question to be a little more flexible (not perfect yet but i can't spend any more time on this now). Don't miss it!

Comment: Hello! i found a problem: the content inside the stretchgrid cannot be clicked cause ListBoxItem handles PreviewMouseDown. The stretchgrid is clickable from the negative left margin to the right border of the image, BUT NOT on the right side of the stretchgrid. I hope it's clear, i'm having hard time fixing this, maybe you have a ready solution. Thanks for your time

Comment: We use it solely for displaying stuff with no interactive element, but i'll look into it and update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done so far:-

Images listed:

[image]

An Image Clicked - will show the Details view below it:

[image]

At the moment I am not closing other Detail Views - so below can happen for me.
However, all this needs is to propagate an event that some other item has been clicked. and close all other Detail Views (its mvvm and driven by a bool property)

[image]

======================================================

I have a Base UserControl which will load Items in a Top Down manner:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GridData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Each Row (Item) of this UserControl itself uses another ItemsControl. So that Images are lined up horizontally. Also, Each Item has a Details View Section (Border with Visibility controlled by Image clicks)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Margin="5" Command="{Binding DataContext.ItemClickedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Image, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Name="DisplayText" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding DisplayText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <Border Margin="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" Padding="10"
                Visibility="{Binding ShowDetailsPanel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="White" CornerRadius="10">
                    <Image Margin="5" Source="{Binding SelectedImage.Image, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </Border>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="20 20 0 0" FontSize="15"
                               Text="{Binding SelectedImage.ImageName, StringFormat={}Filename: {0}}" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="20 20 0 0" FontSize="15"
                               Text="{Binding SelectedImage.Size, StringFormat={}Size: {0} bytes}" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Margin="20 20 0 0" FontSize="15"
                               Text="{Binding SelectedImage.Location, StringFormat={}Path: {0}}" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Margin="20 20 0 0" FontSize="15"
                               Text="{Binding SelectedImage.CreatedTime, StringFormat={}Last Modified: {0}}" Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I know this isnt as neat/finished like the google one - but this is just a PoC

Comment: Did you achieve that with the alternation technique? Snippets?

Comment: Nope... ItemsControl. Posting the xaml.

Comment: Check the updated post. The Details view part was your "witty" idea mate.

Comment: Thank you i'll check and feedback

Comment: @sam - The Trick here is that Each Item in the ItemsControl represents a List of Images; all images in a row share the Details View. Thats why it does not disturb Left & Right Images.

Comment: That's my stategy too

Comment: Your basic idea turned out to be much harder to implement than the accepted solution, but yet feasible. Your idea was very close to mine, of which i have a working implementation taking care of splitting the main list of items in subgroups and render each group on different lists. On scrollviewer kicking in, i'd redraw with less items per row. The only downside was a little delay in the order of hundreads of milliseconds. The accepted solution does not require additional code and does not have this negligible problem. Thank you.